# Spring Reactor: How to zip two Flux, but with order?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

Suppose I have two external services. Let's say we have an item `Foo` and serviceA returns item `A` while serviceB returns item `B`.

What I'd like to get is an handler of the form `(A a, B b)` where `a` and `b` are the corresponding objects for the same queried item.

`Flux::zip` is the closest thing I've found so far, but it's not quite what I'm looking for as order is not promised. I'm looking for something like [CompletableFuture::allOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-)

I can always cheat by making these two calls synchronous but this takes all the fun from reactive programming. Alternatively, I could manage some cache and emit a record only when the two items has been arrived, but I prefer having things stateless.

Comment: what do you mean by "order is not promised"? `zip(A, B, C)` _does_ guarantee that the zipper `Function` will receive an array of `Object` in the `[A, B, C]` order. Only problem is if one of the 3 sources emits less than the others (the result of zip is of the same "size" as its shortest source)

Comment: @SimonBaslé, you're right actually. but I found another problem with `zip()`. It makes you wait for the slowest item before proceeding to the next one. Maybe I'll open another question about it.

Comment: if you mean "it waits for the slowest _source_", then that shouldn't be the case for a truly asynchronous source. Eg. `Mono.delay(ofSeconds(3)).log().zipWith(Mono.delay(ofMillis(500)).log())` should display that source B is subscribed/emits despite source A still being in flight. Perhaps your source A is a blocking callable?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `Flux.flatMap(f1)` or `Flux.flatMap(f2)` before or during the `zip` operation, check if these `flatMap` are executing other asyncronic methods like API endpoint call. In this case maybe you will need to replace them for `Flux.flatMapSequential(f1)` or `Flux.flatMapSequential(f2)` to keep the order of the `flux` elements after the transformations.

Comment: en... lost my day because not read this answer carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout: [concatWith](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#concatWith-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-). You can explore other concat variants as per your requirement.

Note: `Flux.concat(f1, f2)` or `f1.concatWith(f2)` are essentially same.